# Python - Appending matrix to vector in loop

Tags: python, matrix, vector

I'm trying to append several matrices to a vector. My goal is just to create a vector of matrixes.

```
result_array = [] 
for prob in probs:
    countprobstats(values)
    result_array.append(values)
```

The problem is that it looks like it is replacing the previous values with the ones obtained by the function, for instance:

---

From function: [[6.9e-05, 0.000233], [40836.0, 137370.0]]

Vector: [[[6.9e-05, 0.000233], [40836.0, 137370.0]]]

---

From function: [[0.00011, 0.000371], [46236.0, 155531.0]]

Vector: [[[0.00011, 0.000371], [46236.0, 155531.0]], [[0.00011, 0.000371], [46236.0, 155531.0]]]

---

From function: [[0.000148, 0.000498], [55658.0, 186734.0]]

Vector: [[[0.000148, 0.000498], [55658.0, 186734.0]], [[0.000148, 0.000498], [55658.0, 186734.0]], [[0.000148, 0.000498], [55658.0, 186734.0]]]

What is wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `values` is always *the same object* because `countprobstats` modifies it in-place, and you're copying *pointers* to it instead of the actual data.

To solve that, copy the data explicitly:

```
something.append(values.copy())
```

...or have `countprobstats` return the copy instead of doing in-place modifications.